# Building native application with MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are using MobileFirst 6.3 and we are almost finished, but building the native iOS application by adding the environment isn't that easy for us it seems. After creating the environment we tried to run the code, but we are left with a blank screen, which is scrollable, and an error:

```
Error in success callback: DeviceAuth1101721282 = TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard')
```

It appears the Keyboard plugin is not available and the rest of the application won't load any further. Things I tried is adding the plugin found on Github (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard) to the iphone/native/CordovaLib/plugin directory and adding the following code to the iphone/native/config.xml file:

```
<feature name="Keyboard">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVKeyboard" />
</feature>
```

This doesn’t fix the problem. In the documentation how to add native functionality to the application (https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/ios-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/), the next step was to create a function, but I don’t have a function to call at the plugin so I created a temporary function according to the tutorial which only outputs to the console with NSLog. In the log I get the message following by the same error as before.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: What's native in your application? From your explanation it sounds like a hybrid application.

Comment: Sorry, it is an hybrid application and it's not native. I have build an environment for the iPhone and it should also run on Android, but it is completely written in JavaScript with HTML and CSS.

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing. Supply a demo application demonstrating the problem.

Comment: At the moment, the application is quite big and has some private stuff in it, we'll try to create a sample application and we'll update this question with the sample app a.s.a.p.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In one of the tutorial projects for Ionic we followed there was a if-statement which gave the error. We noticed when we wanted to build a smaller version for you to check. It was the one that gave the error.

Comment: So can you write this as an answer or remove the question as it's no longer valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the tutorials to build MobileFirst applications in combination with Ionic Framework, there was an if-statement which gave the error. The if-statement was:

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.keyboard) { ... }
```

While the fix was:

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.keyboard) { ... }
```

Now we have found the fix after 2 days, it seems quite obvious, but this line was somewhat hidden in the project and searching for keyboard gave lots of results.